# how to extract a PERSON named entity after certain word with spacy?

Tags: nlp, extract, spacy, matcher, named-entity-recognition

I have this text ( text2 in code), it has 3 'by' word, I want to use Spacy to extract the person's name (full name, even if it is 3 words, some races use long names, in this case 2). The code is below, my pattern shows error. My intention: first fix the 'by' word with ORTH, then to tell program that whatever coming next is the Part of Speech entity called PERSON. I would be happy if anyone help it:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
text2 = 'All is done by Emily Muller, the leaf is burned by fire. we were not happy, so we cut     relations by saying bye bye'
def extract_person(nlp_doc):
     pattern = [{'ORTH': 'by'}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}}]
     # second possible pattern:
     #pattern = [{"TEXT": "by"}, {"NER": "PERSON"}]
     matcher.add('person_only', None, pattern)
     matches = matcher(nlp_doc)
     for match_id, start, end in matches:
         span = nlp_doc[start:end]
         return span.text
target_doc = nlp(text2)
extract_person(target_doc)
```

I think this question can be asked other way around: how to use NER tags in pattern in Matcher in spacy?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use whole names you should merge entities at the beginning. You can do it by calling: `nlp.add_pipe("merge_entities", after="ner")`

Then in your pattern instead of:

```
pattern = [{"TEXT": "by"}, {"NER": "PERSON"}]
```

Use:

```
pattern = [{"TEXT": "by"}, {"ENT_TYPE": "PERSON"}]
```

Complete code:

```
nlp.add_pipe("merge_entities", after="ner")

text2 = 'All is done by Emily Muller, the leaf is burned by fire. we were not happy, so we cut relations by saying bye bye'

doc = nlp(text2)

pattern = [{"TEXT": "by"}, {"ENT_TYPE": "PERSON"}]

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

matcher.add('person_only', [pattern])
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print(doc[start:end])
```

Comment: I did this: data= ' TEXT PREVIOUS'
doc = nlp(data)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('merge_entities'))
#nlp.add_pipe("merge_entities", after="ner")   # after='ner' shows error
pattern = [{"TEXT": "by"}, {"ENT_TYPE": "PERSON"}]
matcher.add("by", None, pattern)
matches = matcher(doc)
print("Matches:", [doc[start:end].text for match_id, start, end in matches])
#Result:
#Emily Muller 15 27 PERSON
#Matches: ['by Emily']

Comment: Can you please provide some data you're working with? You may also try merging the noun phrases with: `nlp.add_pipe("merge_noun_chunks", last=True)`

Comment: Thank you , I will try. This is the data. objective is to extract PERSON name after 'by' (sometimes there are 3-4 names , most times 2):  text2 = 'All is done by Emily Muller, the leaf is burned by fire. we were not happy, so we cut     relations by saying bye bye'

Comment: Merging noun chunks probably won't help here, but merging entities should take care of this.

Comment: The answer I gave here works for me with your example text

Comment: could you please put whole code here! Because when I tried, this part causes error : nlp.add_pipe("merge_entities", after="ner")

Comment: Krigograbek, As I said it shows error when I run it. Kindly share your code please!

Comment: @Krigograbek: What is "merge_entities"? I can't find any explanation when I googled. Thanks